# android onclick buttons to write strings on Socket

Tags: android, sockets, onclick, android-asynctask

Hi I am building an app which requires the user to press buttons (total 8 buttons). These buttons used to send strings to the server onclick . The problem here I'm having is when i press any of the button after connecting to the server it sends the string as it should but the 2nd time nothing happens. I was suggested to use doInBackground() from AsyncTask, to run keep running the socket and write to it each time the buttons are pressed. But i am unable to do so. What should I do ? I don't know where is the problem. Here I'm putting my code.

This is my Activity

```
public class Acontroller extends Activity {

Button bForward;
Button bBackward;
Button bRight;
Button bLeft;
Button bSelect;
Button bStart;
Button bB;
Button bA;
Socket s;
DataOutputStream os;
String ip;

// MyAppActivity ip = new MyAppActivity();
MyThread start = new MyThread();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.nesskin);

    bForward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bForward);
    bBackward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBackward);
    bRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRight);
    bLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLeft);
    bSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSelect);
    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    bA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA);
    bB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB);

    Bundle gotIP = getIntent().getExtras();
    ip = gotIP.getString("ipAddress");


//  start.doInBackground(ip);
    //start.execute(ip);
    // sock.start();

}

protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    bForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            start.execute(ip);
        }
    });
```

And from the thread.

```
public class MyThread extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{


Socket s;
DataOutputStream os;
String ip;
String cmd;


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      Log.i("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
  }



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    int port = 2222;


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(s.isConnected()){
        try {
            os.writeUTF("forward");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{



    try {
    s= new Socket(ip, port);
    os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    os.writeUTF("forward");

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    finally{
          if (s!= null){
           try {
            s.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
          }

          if (os != null){
           try {
            os.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
          }
    }


}


    return null;
}
```

My objective is as many times the user clicks the buttons the respective strings must be send to the server. Here is my server code I'm using PC as server.

```
public class Server


public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    String msg_received = null;
    String fw = "forward";
    String bw = "backward";
    String l = "left";
    String r = "right";
    String se = "select";
    String st = "start";
    String a = "a";
    String b = "b";
    String fin = "finish";
//  Boolean finish = (msg_received.equal(fin));
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2222);
        System.out.println("Server Started...");

        while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();

            System.out.println("Connection Request Received");

            DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            msg_received = DIS.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msg_received);
            // s.close();
            // ss.close();

            if (msg_received.equals(fw)) {
                // tu yeh kerna

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);

            }
```

Please help me it really important to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-use an AsyncTask.  You have to create a new object and call execute.

Replace

start.execute();

with

start = new MyThread();
start.execute(ip);

or if you can get away with removing the instance when it's done, then you can just do this:

(new MyThread()).start();

EDIT:

To send parameters to AsyncTask, do this:

start.execute(ip, cmd, param3, param4, param5);

in `doInBackground` collect the parameters like so:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
{
   String ipParam = params[0];
   String cmdParam = params[1];
   String thirdParam = params[2];
   String fourthParam = params[3];
   String fifthParam = params[4];
}
```

You can pass as many Strings as you want into `params` and it will automatically create a new array containing all the parameters at runtime.  Just note that if you only pass in two, then the `params` size will only be two.  If you pass in 100 parameters, then `params` will be 100 units in size.

Comment: the code in myThread class is fine? and how do i pass my string which is to be sent to socket? by using just start.execute() ? what is the way to write on the socket as many times i want then close is when i want to exit the app?

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're keeping the socket open in your AsyncTask.  If you need it open throughout the entire life of the app, then you need to move it out and close it in `onPause()`. HOWEVER, it would most likely be best open it in `doInBackground` and close it in the `onPostExecute()` method of AsyncTask.  Do all cleanup in that method.  The string can be sent as a parameter when you call `execute()`.  If you're retrieving it, then you need to either keep the reference to the AsyncTask until you collect it, or store it somewhere.

Comment: I can't comment on the correctness of the socket code as I personally haven't done network coding much in my apps, and I don't have them with me right now.  Your problem was that the `AsyncTask` was only running once, and I know this is the reason.

Comment: on execute i want to send the string ip and the string cmd. cmd is defined in the activity class.

Comment: Now i want to ask is there a way that when the user presses and hold the button for any specific time will it increment a variable according to the duration the button is pressed ? so that i can use it in a loop ? or is there a method using which i can get the delay or duration of the button pressed and hold?

Comment: Create an `OnTouchListener` that posts to a `Handler` on even `ACTION_DOWN`.  The `Handler` calls `postDelayed` to itself.  Remove all the callbacks to the `Handler` on `ACTION_UP`.   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: would touchlistener work fine if i already have onclick on buttons? i mean im using one button both for onclick and ontouch ?

Comment: It would take work to get them to work properly usually.  I think `onClick` activates on ACTION_UP.  It would be best (or maybe easier) to use `onTouch` to handle everything.  You have to decide yourself when the "click" event should fire.

Comment: ok just made a while loop like while (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){  and here im executing the thread and then break;  }  well i doesnt work when i press and hold any idea ?

Comment: I think it would be best to make another question regarding making long press.  That topic is out of scope of this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824867/android-executing-the-thread-in-a-loop-with-ontouchlistener